# Integrals and Legendre Polynomials

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

I was told by a professor that this equality:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|r-r(\varphi)|}d\varphi = \frac{1}{r}\sum_0^{\infty} \bigl(\frac{a}{r}\bigr)^n{|P_n(0)|}^2$$

( where:
$a$ is the constant modulo of the vector $r'(\varphi)$ and $P_n(0)$ is the $n$th Legendre Polynomial evaluated in $0$  ).

Is a very well-known fact among physicists and often used as a sort of definition of the Legendre Polynomials.

The problem is that the only Legendre Polynomial definition I know is Rodrigue's one:

$$ P_n(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$

How can I prove that these two definitions coincide?

I evaluated the integral by studying the "mean value" of $|r-r(\varphi)|^{-1}$ as a Taylor expansion and I could verify by hand that the first terms really behave as expected, but for obvious reasons I cannot verify *all* of them...

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137609/2451

Comment: Klest: I don't believe that physicians know *anything* about the Legendre polynomials. ;-) By the way, what is $a$? It only appears on one side. Oh, I see, the result is independent of $a$, it's just scaling the orbit.

Comment: What is $r(\varphi)$? Is it related to $a$?

Comment: Edited, now things should be ok.

Comment: @Qmechanics, the questions are closely related, but as nobody could answer me to the first one, I'm trying with something easier :-)

Answer (score 4):

[It's known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplacesEquationSphericalCoordinates.html) that the general solution of the Laplace equation $\nabla^2\Phi = 0$ in spherical coordinates with azimutal symmetry is given by:

$$\Phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(A_l r^l + B_lr^{-(l+1)}\right)P_l(\cos \theta),$$
where $A_l$ and $B_l$ are given by boundary conditions. We also have that the function $\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}$, where $\mathbf{x'}$ is the location of a charge (or mass) satisfies the Laplace equation. Thus we can write
$$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(A_l r^l + B_lr^{-(l+1)}\right)P_l(\cos \theta)$$

If the points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x'}$lie in the $z$ axis, we have that the LHS is
$$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}=\frac{1}{|r-r'|},$$
while the RHS is
$$\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(A_l r^l + B_lr^{-(l+1)}\right),$$
since $P_l(\cos 0)=1$. Expanding $\dfrac{1}{|r-r'|}$ for $r>r'$, we get
$$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}=\frac{1}{r}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^l$$
Since the expasion is unique, we get that $A_l=0$, $\forall l$, and $B_l=r'^l$. For $\mathbf{x}$ out of the axis, we just have to multiply each term by $P_l(\cos \theta)$. We get then the expression
$$\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}=\frac{1}{r}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^lP_l(\cos \gamma),$$
where $\gamma$ is the angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x'}$. In you case, since the $\gamma=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, you find that on the $z$ axis, the potential is given by
$$\Phi(r)=-\frac{GM}{r}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^lP_l(0)$$
A similar procedure yields the result for $r<r'$.

Comment: Why is your answer missing the exponent "$^2$" over the $P_l$ s? And is there any way to get the solution without involving the Laplace equation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware about. The exponent doesn't exist. My answer is based on section 3.3 of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics. You can check more details and properties of Legendre polynomials there. In the section there's also the example of a ring with $z$ as axis, and the potential has no square in the $P_l(0)$.

Comment: @MateusSampaio If the points ${\vec x}$ and ${\vec x}^\prime$ lie in the z-axis, should it not be equal to $1/|z-z'|$?

Comment: @Solidification Yes, but in this case, $r=z$ and $r'=z'$.